# Are all bounded operators a compact operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. I was trying for a bounded operator which is not compact operator.

My attempt:-
I got this example from a textbook  "Hilbert Space Operators in Quantum Physics" by Jiří Blank, Pavel Exner, Miloslav Havlíček.
Why does unit operator infinite dimensional subspace of $H$ is bounded but not a compact operator.

I was confused whether the author mean for identity operator or a unitary operator.
We can see that either identity operator or unitary operator is bounded. How do I prove that it is not compact?

Comment: Well, bounded operators are (in the usual sense of the words that I'm used to seeing) are just the continuous linear maps. Not every continuous linear map is compact in infinite dimensions

Comment: I'm not used to the word "unit operator", but I'm guessing it's the identity map ($x \mapsto x$). When the space is infinite-dimensional, this is indeed bounded, but not compact. Proving this depends on how the book specifically defines compact operators, but it often has something to do with taking an orthonormal sequence (which is bounded, and must exist by Gram-Schmidt), and showing it maps to a sequence that has no convergent subsequence. The same logic will work for any unitary operator as well.

Comment: identity operator would be a better term. I agree that "unit operator" is not a good term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the identity operator on the unit sphere  in

$l_2\iff (\forall x)\left(x=\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}, x_i\in R\;, \forall i, \;
||x||^2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty{x_i^2}<\infty\right)$

now this operator is bounded on the unit sphere.

now take the sequence

$x_n=\delta_{in}$
i.e  the sequence of zeros with 1 at the nth location.

It is clear that $\{x_n\}\subseteq S$
yet it is not Cauchy.

$||x_n-x_m||=\sqrt{2}, n\neq m$

so any subsequence you take will not converge.

the unit sphere is not compact.

and so the identity operator is not compact.